# Apache proxy to Glassfish - How to supress subfolder in URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, glassfish, proxypass

I've got a single linux server running Apache/2.2.24 running both HTTP/HTTPS along with a Glassfish 3.1.2 server listening on port 8080.

Glassfish runs a single deployed application which has subfolders for separate websites, e.g.:

```
http://gfish:8080/rootSite
http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site2
http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site3
http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site4
```

In the Apache `vhosts.conf` file all traffic to port 80 of each Virtual Host is re-written to 443 as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site2.com/rootSite/Site2$1 [L,R]
```

In the Apache `ssl.conf` file each virtual host is configured to pass off to Glassfish as follows:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ https://www.site2.com/rootSite/Site2$1
ProxyPass /rootSite/ http://gfish:8080/rootSite/
ProxyPassReverse /rootSite/ http://gfish:8080/rootSite/
```

The end result for a web-user is that when they navigate to `http://www.site2.com` they are redircted to HTTPS and proxied to Glassfish resulting in them seeing: `https://www.site2.com/rootSite/Site2`

This is the current working configuration.

The **desired** results is that the web-user does not see the subfolder and sees the site as: `https://www.site2.com`

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this given the existing configuration?

**EDIT:**

After some toying around it appears that some of the configuration within the ssl.conf file is unnecessary.  I trimmed it down to the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site2/`
```

With this new configuration I am able to omit the /rootSite/Site2/ from the URL as desired **however** all CSS formatting and images are broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the Apache `vhosts.conf` file I change the rewrite rule as such:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site2.com$1 [L,R]`

In the `ssl.conf` file I trimmed it down to:

`ProxyRequests Off`

`ProxyPass /rootSite/ http://gfish:8080/rootSite/`
`ProxyPassReverse /rootSite/ http://gfish:8080/rootSite/`

This first set of Proxy statements was added because Site2 relies on CSS and Image files from the rootSite in order to render pages.

`ProxyPass / http://rootSite:8080/rootSite/Site2/`
`ProxyPassReverse / http://rootSite:8080/rootSite/Site2/`

The second set of Proxy statements hooks the external root of the website to the internal Glassfish Site2 root.

This configuration gave me the desired result of external users seeing `https://www.site2.com/`

**THE NEW PROBLEM**

I handed this configuration off to the developers for testing and it turns out that there are absolute URLs in their code which they aren't willing to change.  In this case, the home page has a login form and the form action points to the absolute URL of `http://www.site2.com/rootSite/site2/login.xhtml`  Any web-user clicking on the form submit button is then redirected to the site, again revealing the unwanted subfolders in the URL.

The solution I've been striving towards is to implement and configure `mod_proxy_html`.

To that end I compiled the necessary information into Apache to enable the module and then created an `proxy_html.conf` file with the following content:

`ProxyHTMLLinks  a               href`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  area            href`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  link            href`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  img             src longdesc usemap`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  object          classid codebase data usemap`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  q               cite`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  blockquote      cite`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  ins             cite`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  del             cite`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  form            action`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  input           src usemap`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  head            profile`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  base            href`
`ProxyHTMLLinks  script          src for`

`ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \`
                `onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \`
                `onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \`
                `onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange`

Within the `ssl.conf` file I adjusted the Proxy configuration as follows:

`ProxyPass /rootSite/ http://gfish:8080/rootSite/`
`ProxyPassReverse /rootSite/ http://gfish:8080/rootSite/`

`ProxyRequests Off`
`ProxyPass / http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site2/`
`<Location />`
`ProxyPassReverse /`
`ProxyHTMLEnable On`
`ProxyHTMLURLMap http://gfish:8080/rootSite/Site2/ /`
`ProxyHTMLURLMap / /`
`</Location>`

Unfortunately even with this in place I am not achieving the desired result of having the Form action link re-written.

Input and insight is more than welcome.